# MongoDB Replication on Windows Machine

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset

I am on Windows Environment, I want to create a replication on Mongodb. When I will generate the replica set on  cmd it returns an error of syntax that is missing ; before statement. 
My command is

```
mongod --replSet abctest --logpath \data\primary\primary.log --dbpath \data\primary --port 27017 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
```

can anyone suggest me that where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: The error suggests you are trying to run this command within a `mongo` shell rather than from a Windows `cmd.exe` shell. FYI:  `--smallfiles` is only applicable to the legacy MMAPv1 storage engines;  modern versions of MongoDB (3.2+) default to the WiredTiger storage engine. I recommend following a [replica set tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/replica-set-deployment/) in the manual for the version of MongoDB server you are using. For future questions it would also be helpful to include your specific MongoDB server version (x.y.z) in order to get relevant advice.